# Laravel elequent pivot table using where

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

How can I use Laravel to do something like this:

Tables:

```
projects:
id,name, active

pivot table: project_users
id, project_id, user_id
```

If I do this, I get good results, including all users of the project

```
Project::with('users')->where('active', '=', 1)->get();
```

But how can I filter on users and on active ? something like ?

```
Project::with('users')->where('active', '=', 1)->where('users',=,3)->get();
```

or ??

```
Project::with('users')->where('active', '=', 1)->where('users.user_id',=,3)->get();
```

Comment: You should explain what exactly you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict rows in the table you are eager loading then you can add constraints to the eager load where you can perform your usual `QueryBuilder` operations on the `$query`. So in your example we can do the following:

```
Project::with(['users' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('user_id', '=', 3);

}])->where('active', '=', 1)->get();
```

This is assuming `active` is accessible to your initial table before the eager load.

Comment: Thanks! only 'users' = > function  should be 'users' => function